# Do I use italics for hotel and restaurant names?

Tags: italics

I'm writing a bio for a friend, and I mention many hotels and restaurants, some of which are foreign. Should I use italics?

Comment: why do you think you should?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of italics in writing](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/)

Answer (score 5):

I would say no. Here is a quick guide on the correct usage of  [italics](http://www.ehow.com/how_5951_italics.html). To summarize: Don't use it for the proper noun. They example they give for a restaurant: if you write about a certain dish you ate that might not be commonly known, italicize it, but do not italicize the restaurant name.

Comment: Do you mind adding a summary of the relavant part from the link?

Comment: I'm sure I irritate the hell out of some people on this site because I overuse italics. But I probably wouldn't use them just to highlight one class of nouns (i.e. - hotels and restaurants) unless the writing was specifically *about* objects of that class, where I wanted to be sure the reader would easily pick them out from a mass of verbiage.

Comment: @MrHen: Sure thing. Don't use it for the proper noun. They example they give for a restaurant: if you write about a certain dish you ate that might not be commonly known, italicize it, but do not italicize the restaurant name.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I added it to the body of the answer others' convenience. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is the consideration that a restaurant name might be confused for a geographical location in some cases; you could use quotation marks around the name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -1):

No you don't, just capitalize the name.

Comment: Please consider giving a rationale for your answer.