# Why is this ‘loved’ italicized?

Tags: meaning-in-context, italics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of italics in writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/usage-of-italics-in-writing)

> “But I was patient. I wrote back. I was sympathetic, I was kind. Ginny simply *loved* me. No one’s ever understood me like you, Tom...*I’m so glad I’ve got this diary to confide in...It’s like having a friend I can carry around in my pocket...*” Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (p.309, US edition).

The speaker, Tom Riddle, is a villain in this story. He is boasting how well he could win Ginny’s heart by becoming a kind of pen pal with her.

I understand the latter part is italicized because Tom is mimicking Ginny’s comment. But why is “loved” written in italics? Or, if you were the writer, how would you express the same meaning without italics?

Comment: Hi @totoro, have you though about asking this question on the [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange? It would probably fit better than here…

Comment: In the future, could you please actually *italicize* the italicized parts? Thank you.

Comment: @F’x  Thank you for your helpful information! I’ll do that.  @RegDwight  Oops! Thank you, and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @everyone  Thank you for your attention and useful discussion!

Answer (score 1):

In this context, *[italic type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italics)* is being used for [emphasis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emphasis):

> 1. Special weight or forcefulness given to something considered important.
> 2. Special attention or prominence given to something.

**Bold face** may also be used for similar effect.

Comment: Uhm, I don't really agree about the bold being used for the same thing... Usually in books only the italics is used to highlight something, I can't recall ever seeing a word being bold in a book.

Comment: @Alenanno: see also the Wikipedia article on [emphasis in typography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_%28typography%29).

Comment: @Alenanno bold may not be used as much classically, but it is certainly widespread.

Comment: thanks for the link @Rory: I don't know every book on this Earth, obviously :D but honestly I don't remember ever seeing the bold being used... Maybe italian editors don't use it! lol :D