# Sarcasm within thoughts

Tags: italics, thought

When I write sarcasm, I put it in italic writing, like; *what a beautiful sweater*. I also do this when writing third person perspective characters like; *he's ugly*. But what if the character is thinking something sarcastic. Like for example, the character meets someone called John Smith. So then he sarcastically thinks; *creative name*. Apologies to anyone called John Smith. Anyway, considering thoughts are already in italic, there's not way of showing what's sarcasm. Sure, one can use one's brain, but that's not always reliable, for two reasons. First, opinions are subjective, so one might think that John Smith is a very unique name (statistically it isn't). Secondly, there is autistic readers out there who simply might not get the sarcasm without a clear pointing finger to it. I was not trying to be hurtful back there, I'm just stating the facts. -Not seeing sarcasm and not being good at communication in general are traits of autism. Anyway, back to the question. How to make sarcasm visually clear within already italicized writing? It's a question of writing technicality, I believe.

Comment: Do you include a note somewhere in the things that you write explaining that you use italics to mark sarcasm? As far as I know, this is not a common convention, so I wouldn't consider it "a clear pointing finger" in any context.

Comment: @sumelic Perhaps, but I believe if italics are used on one word in a sentence that's debateably sarcastic, then people will figure it out. In a thought were everything is italicized anyway, you don't get the same effect.

Comment: In good writing, readers shouldn't need typographical cues to determine sarcasm.

Comment: I agree with @KarlG, you should try to convey it in the text. In this case, I'd write something like "Wow, real creative name"

Comment: Following on @KarlG point on quality writing - I would suggest you take this question to the stack overflow writers forum https://writing.stackexchange.com/   Which point of view you are writing from (first person , etc)  would dictate some choices  -  I am not sure this is really an English language question

Comment: Just noted your request for 'visual' clarity .  I am not so sure meaning is expected to be visual in our phonetically written language ?  I might not object to your use of italics but it is not really a standard convention at all and not all readers would get that meaning although they would probably begin to see the convention you chose over the length of a longer piece with repeated use of it that way

Comment: 'I believe if italics are used on one word in a sentence that's debateably [sic] sarcastic, then people will figure it out.'  I don't. Italics are conventionally used for [various other reasons](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/usage-of-italics-in-writing). Even here, confusion as to which usage is intended can occur. D-I-Y applications are very unwise and off-topic on a site devoted to accepted English usage.

Comment: We should start with an understanding of what sarcasm is:  a particular form of irony, where the irony is intended to insult, offend or diminish a person or institution.  Your examples are fair ones.  Irony, in the sense in which sarcasm is related to it, involves making a point by saying the opposite of what the speaker believes in such a way (or context) that people will get the humour.  So Boris Johnson might say:  “As you know, I am a master of understatement.”.  No need for italics or a special tone of voice. Sarcasm is just an unpleasant form of this, designed to hurt someone.

Comment: @KarlG I see what you mean, and I think you might have answered my question. I searched around and a website said you don't need italics. You can simply hyperbole, meaning you clearly overstate the sentence. I thought of this, but now I have gotten confirmation. But, as some of you said, italics are actually a way to convey sarcasm in my written language. Or at least that's what I've experience reading books.

Comment: I follow a sentence with a tilde (~) or /sarc to indicate sarcasm.  I will often use italics without quote marks to indicate an internal dialogue.  So, to answer your question, combine the two.